# Facebook into mobile app

Tags: facebook, mobile, titanium, integrate

I am making a mobile application in Appcelerator Titanium. I would like to integrate facebook in my app. I have 2 questions about this.

1. How do i open a page instead of an app? Because it asks for an AppID, but a page doesn't have it right? So I'm wondering can I implement a page into my mobile app, so you can post on that page with your own account? (for example page by greenpeace or amnesty international?)
2. My second one is how can I integrate login on my app with a pop-up screen? (I mean a pop up screen like you have to login with twitter, not that it goes to the facebook page on safari browser, so the app gets closed)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/3475322559/titanium-appcelerator-quickie-facebook-oauth-in-1-6-0

This is an iOS approach

Comment: Thanks, But that link is outdated i think, it won't open.. Is that possible? I tried to open it by going to your site, but when i click the blog over there it gives the same error.

Greats

Answer (score 0):

My dear you just need to go through deeply with this [Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/). You can find every thing that you want

Comment: Looking into the example app of Titanium with facebook, but that one goes to the browser directly, Found out that you have to surf to the browser by googling... And after a while of googling i still did not found any way to include a PAGE, and not an APP by facebook... such as Amnesty International, Music For Life, ...

Answer (score 0):

Titanium has its own [Facebook API](https://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Facebook-module), maybe that will solve your problems?